# How to unselect an object from a UITableView?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

I was wondering how I could unselect an object from my `UITableView`. One of the cells is highlighted, or selected, and I want to unselect it so that none of the `UITableView` cells are selected. How could I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this:

```
[yourTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[yourTableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you gain a reference to the cell, you can also call

```
cell.selected = NO;
```